# Getting Protoype Error in Magento Checkout Onepage

Tags: magento, prototypejs

I have read and searched through site about the prototype error I am getting during checkout on our site.

What is happening is that when onepage goes to the shipping methods part the display is showing none. after reading through other questions usually the prototype error is from a jquery.no conflict issue. I have exhausted that option and don't believe it is the issue. I am hoping there is something else for me to try.

Our issue is here https://rmi-online.com/checkout/onepage/

Everything works fine until you click continue on billing info and it goes to shipping method. Then it is just blank. This is painful because noone can place an order with the site. The frustrating issue is that it was working correctly but now it doesn't for some reason. I can't figure out what changed.

Comment: is your error `Translator is not defined` ?

Comment: That one has shown it's ugly head from time to time actually. But the main error I keep getting is registry undefined.

Comment: Do you have a line number of the registry error and where its being called from? The Translator error is because `Translator` is an instance of the Translate class - but not being created ie `var Translator = new Translate(data);`

Comment: the error is: TypeError: registry is undefined
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js
Line 5557

Comment: OK that is referring to the Event registry and the `observe()` method.  Also you are using an older version of PrototypeJS - can you change the reference to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1/prototype.js ?

Comment: As far as the observers - there are multiple places in your JS that call the `observe()` method - I have a feeling it has something to do with the form validation or the forms - When I go through it I don't see any shipping method - can you turn that back on so I can help you more?

Comment: I updated the prototype. Received more errors now. Registry one is gone. I do have the shipping method turned on. When viewing source I am seeing it. Are you not?

Comment: This is my new error with and updated prototype.js....
TypeError: element is null
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1/prototype.js
Line 6385

Comment: using OSX Chrome I get the same Translator error - but no shipping methods show and no other errors

Comment: I think we will backup to the time it was working and go from there. Don't know how to fix the issue other than that.